# Probability of Normal Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Let's say that 10 sumo wrestlers were to squeeze into an elevator that could only hold a max capacity of 2300 pounds. Let's say that the weight of the sumo wrestlers is normally distributed with a mean of 220 lbs and a standard deviation of 25 pounds, what's the probability that the elevator is past it's max cap.?

So far I have that

μ = 220
 σ = 25

I thought of (2300-2200)/25
            = 4 (but that doesn't seem right. )

and something like P {X > 2300} = Pr {Z>what apparently 4 would be} = 1 - (something here)

I'm not sure if I'm even doing this problem right.

Comment: The sum of the weights has variance $(10)(25^2)$, so standard deviation $25\sqrt{10}$. I think you were working along the correct lines, but using the wrong standard deviation.

Comment: wait what? so it would be 2300-2200 / 25 sqrt 10?

Comment: The probability of being over capacity is $\Pr\left(Z\gt \frac{2300-2200}{25\sqrt{10}}\right)$.

Comment: You are welcome. The probability that $Z\gt a$ is not found in most tables of the standard normal, which give instead $\Pr(Z\le a)$. But from that $\Pr(Z\gt a)$ is easily found. If you are using software, how to enter the problem is program-dependent.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X_i=\text{N}(220,25^2)$ be the weight of the $i^\text{th}$ wrestler.

Then $X=\sum_iX_i$ be the total weight.

Now read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables and [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini's_theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) and note that Fubini's theorem applies to random variables.